# Stackoverflow trouble with a BinarySearch in VB 2010

Tags: database, vb.net, algorithm, recursion, stack-overflow

```
Public Sub BinarySearch_Surname(ByVal BrownieArray() As Brownie_Structure, ByVal SearchItem As String, ByVal LowInt As Integer, ByVal HighInt As Integer)
    Dim ItemFound As Boolean = False
    Dim SearchFailed As Boolean = False
    Dim Midpoint As Integer = Int((LowInt + HighInt) / 2)

    Try
        If BrownieArray(Midpoint).Surname = SearchItem Then
            ItemFound = True
        Else
            If LowInt >= HighInt Then
                SearchFailed = True
            Else
                If BrownieArray(Midpoint).Surname < SearchItem Then
                    **BinarySearch_Surname(BrownieArray, Midpoint + 1, HighInt, ItemFound)
                Else
                    BinarySearch_Surname(BrownieArray, LowInt, Midpoint - 1, HighInt)**
                End If
            End If
        End If
        If SearchFailed = True Then
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to find Suranme in database", "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If ItemFound = True Then
            MessageBox.Show("Surname: " & BrownieArray(Midpoint).Surname, "Found", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Catch
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to find , please insert correct infomation and try again", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        Exit Sub
    End Try
End Sub
```

StackOverflow occurs with this recursive algorithm, I know why the error is caused but do not know how to fix it?

Comment: Please ad the Header of BinarySearch_Surname() so we can see the parameters. But you are changing MidPoint in a way that seems not to be 'middle'.

Comment: Use Array.BinarySearch() or the [homework] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
If LowInt >= HighInt Then
```

Should be:

```
If LowInt > HighInt Then
```

This line:

```
BinarySearch_Surname(BrownieArray, Midpoint + 1, HighInt, ItemFound)
```

Should be:

```
BinarySearch_Surname(BrownieArray, SearchItem, Midpoint + 1, HighInt)
```

This line:

```
BinarySearch_Surname(BrownieArray, LowInt, Midpoint - 1, HighInt)
```

Should be:

```
BinarySearch_Surname(BrownieArray, SearchItem, LowInt, Midpoint - 1)
```

Comment: Sorry this is still not working, I still don't know why? Can you please look over it again thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the wrong parameters to the recursive call, It should be like that:

```
  If BrownieArray(Midpoint).Surname < SearchItem Then
      BinarySearch_Surname(BrownieArray, SearchItem, Midpoint + 1, HighInt)
  Else
      BinarySearch_Surname(BrownieArray, SearchItem, LowInt, Midpoint - 1)                
  End If
```

Also your recursion exit condition is wrong, it should be:

```
  If LowInt > HighInt Then // > instead of >=
```

Furthermore you could turn your `SUB` into a function that returns a value, so that you keep those message boxes out of your search code.